Can't add foreign key constraint on a "multiple column" unique references
I get these error
SQL Error [1822] [HY000]: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'rel_employee_kriterias_kode_kriteria_foreign' in the referenced table 'kriterias'

when i want to add foreign key constraint on a "multiple column unique" key
Here is what my tables look like
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255),
  `address` varchar(255),
  `phone_number` varchar(255),
  `gender` enum('male','female'),
  `created_at` timestamp,
  `updated_at` timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `kelompok_kriterias` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nama_kelompok_kriteria` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `kriterias` (
  `id` bigint unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kode_kriteria` varchar(255),
  `nama_kriteria` varchar(255),
  `bobot` int NOT NULL,
  `kelompok_kriteria_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `kriterias_kelompok_kriteria_id_kode_kriteria_unique` (`kelompok_kriteria_id`,`kode_kriteria`),
  CONSTRAINT `kriterias_kelompok_kriteria_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`kelompok_kriteria_id`) REFERENCES `kelompok_kriterias` (`id`)
);

And the table that i want to create is this relation table
CREATE TABLE `rel_employee_kriterias` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `kode_kriteria` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nilai` int NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rel_employee_kriterias_employee_id_kode_kriteria_unique` (`employee_id`,`kode_kriteria`),
  CONSTRAINT `rel_employee_kriterias_employee_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id`)
  CONSTRAINT `rel_employee_kriterias_kode_kriteria_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`kode_kriteria`) REFERENCES `kriterias` (`kode_kriteria`)
);

The error occured on this line
CONSTRAINT `rel_employee_kriterias_kode_kriteria_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`kode_kriteria`) REFERENCES `kriterias` (`kode_kriteria`)

is there any solution for my problem?

kode_kriteria is not constrained to be unique in kriterias, it is part of a compound key along with kelompok_kriteria_id, so to reference this unique key in a foreign key, your referencing table must also include kelompok_kriteria_id. They also require the same collation in each table to be compatible - https://dbfiddle.uk/d63aOpuy

@GarethD thank you, it works.. Could you write an answer for it? So i can check it as an answer?

kode_kriteria is not constrained to be unique in kriterias, it is part of a composite key along with kelompok_kriteria_id, so to reference this unique key in a foreign key, your referencing table must also include kelompok_kriteria_id.
CREATE TABLE `rel_employee_kriterias` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `kode_kriteria` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `kelompok_kriteria_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL, -- Required
  `nilai` int NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rel_employee_kriterias_employee_id_kode_kriteria_unique` (`employee_id`,`kode_kriteria`),
  CONSTRAINT `rel_employee_kriterias_employee_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `rel_employee_kriterias_kode_kriteria_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`kelompok_kriteria_id`, `kode_kriteria`) REFERENCES `kriterias` (`kelompok_kriteria_id`, `kode_kriteria`)
);

N.B. They also require the same collation in each table to be compatible, so you either need to specify COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci in both tables, or in neither table for it to work.
Example on db<>fiddle
